# Firebase unit testing without involving a context

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, firebase

I am trying to unit test firebase code with JUnit 4 in Android Studio.

The following are the minimal unit test code and configs.

```
public class ATest {
    private static Firebase f;
    @BeforeClass
    public static void init() {
        f = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
    }
    @Test
    public void doTest(){}
}
```

build.gradle dependency

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-jvm:2.5.0'
}
```

However, when running unit testing, exception occur at the line inside `init()`.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: You need to set the Android context using Firebase.setAndroidContext() before using Firebase.
    at com.firebase.client.core.Context.getPlatform(Context.java:45)
    at com.firebase.client.core.Context.ensureLogger(Context.java:218)
    at com.firebase.client.core.Context.initServices(Context.java:105)
    at com.firebase.client.core.Context.freeze(Context.java:92)
    at com.firebase.client.core.RepoManager.getLocalRepo(RepoManager.java:55)
    at com.firebase.client.core.RepoManager.getRepo(RepoManager.java:19)
    at com.firebase.client.Firebase.<init>(Firebase.java:172)
    at com.firebase.client.Firebase.<init>(Firebase.java:177)
    at com.firebase.client.Firebase.<init>(Firebase.java:155)
    at mypackage.Test.init(Test.java:21)
```

I did a test with eclipse/maven, including firebase-client-jvm doesn't result in `RuntimeException`. What configuration am I missing to cause the jvm version of Firebase to require a Context?